# Disposing ObservableCollection<>

Tags: c#-4.0, observablecollection, idisposable

Do we need to dispose each item inside a `ObservableCollection` while dispoing the container class? Or can we just dispose the container class, it will dispose all objects inside that class. Say for example:

```
  public class SomeClass : IDisposable
  {

      private ObservableCollection<JobItem> jobItemTemplates = new ObservableCollection<JobItem>(); 
      public ObservableCollection<JobItem> JobItemTemplates
      {
        get 
        {
            return this.jobItemTemplates; 
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.jobItemTemplates != value)
            {
                this.jobItemTemplates = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("JobItemTemplates");
            }
        }
    }
 }

  protected override void OnDispose()
  {        
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    if (this.jobTreeItemViewModelItem != null)
    {
        foreach(JobTreeItemViewModel  item in this.jobTreeItemViewModelItem)
        {
             item.Dispose();
        }
        this.jobTreeItemViewModelItem.Clear();
     }

     this.jobTreeItemViewModelItem = null;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObservableCollection does not implement IDisposable and it doesn't check the type of the items either. So you'll have to dispose of the items by hand (or implement a IDisposable container for the disposables)

Comment: What if My `SomeClass` will have an object of `AnotherClass` which is implements IDisposable. Does it mean, I need to explicitly dispose the 'AnotherClass` object? Disposing `SomeClass` will not dispose the `AnotherClass` object?

Comment: @Saroj - Correct. You could create a class that acts as a collection of IDisposables that is Disposable itself. In its Dispose method you would still have to dispose all the objects in the collection.